# Linq SelectMany in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm using Entity Framework. My typical access functionality would be something like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Product> Category(string category, int term)
    {
        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(Connections.LoanComparision))
        {
            var r = new Repository<Product>(uow.Context);

            return r.Find(x => x.Category == category)
                .Include(x => x.ProductDetails)
                .Include(x => x.ProductRates)
                .Include(x => x.Provider)
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

You will note from the code above 2 things.

- The query returns a list of products with a category including linked
  entities.
- There are a number of ProductDetail lines for each Product.

What I want to do (and haven't been able to work out) is to apply selection criteria on the ProductDetails table.

The stuff inside .Find (my function) can be replaced by a standard .Where clause, but I need to filter on MinTerm and MaxTerm (which is in ProductDetails) yet still return the complete Product dataset (including linked entities), not just ProductDetails.

```
Where(x => term >= x.MinTerm && term <= x.MaxTerm)
```

I can work out how to do it by referencing ProductDetails first and linking to other tables but can't in this configuration. Is it possible?

Comment: No. To solve this, you should either return an `IEnumerable<ProductDetail>` or use custom types and projection.

Comment: Just join products with product details for filtering, then select everything you need

Comment: @KonstantinErshov - Don't completely understand, please can you clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the relationship between `Product` and `ProductDetail` is one to many you could do this:

```
var query= context.ProductDetails.Include(pd=>pd.Product.ProductRates)
                                 .Include(pd=>pd.Product.Provider)
                                 .Where(pd=> pd.Product.Category == category 
                                             && term >= pd.MinTerm && term <= pd.MaxTerm);
```

And if you want the list of products you could do the following:

```
var query1=query.Select(pd=>pd.Product).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Along the lines of my alternative option but I hadn't worked out the Distinct but. Pretty neat.

Comment: But something like this is what you are looking for?. I haven't understood yet what is the result you are expecting. Could you clarify more in your question?.

Comment: The function is a comparision table, so in the first instance I'll be looking to retrieve products that match the criteria (there is more). Because, the data is fairly static and not too large I'm looking at possibly caching it which could then be used for other queries too.

Comment: And when you try to execute my last query, what was the result? It should load the related entities too

Comment: Not quite at that stage yet - still putting together some test stuff so I can try it.